# How can I separate the sections in an INI file?

Tags: delphi, ini

When saving to an INI file, especially when more than one section is defined, the data is saved all together with no lines between the sections.

For external editing purposes it would be handy to separate each section with a line break, to make it easier to view and edit the INI file.

**For Example:**

**Standard Ini**

```
[GENERAL]
value1=0
value2=somestring
[ADVANCED]
type=1
autosave=0
[OTHER]
showatstartup=1
```

**Ini with seperating lines**

```
[GENERAL]
value1=0
value2=somestring

[ADVANCED]
type=1
autosave=0

[OTHER]
showatstartup=1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you considered moving to XML for readibility?

Comment: @Mike: XML is supposed to be better readable than INI? You can't be serious!

Comment: @Mike: I let users edit ini files, when creating a GUI to change a setting is not cost-effective.  I wouldn't trust those users to edit an XML file by hand though.

Comment: In many countries it is considered a violation of basic human rights to expect people to read XML files.

Comment: @dummzeuch: For extremely long ini files, definitely serious. Not for short ones, but I gathered from the request that we're talking about long files here.

Comment: I know about XML, but like dummzeuch said, XML is not a neat way to save the data for reading purposes. I actually use XML to save some Treeview Data to file in a project, I am using INI file to save application preferences. The likeleyhood of the user editing it externally is not likely, but even so INI is clearer to read, especially with Rob's answer of adding a line break between sections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the file and insert empty lines before each section name. Here's a function for it:

```
procedure InsertSectionLineBreaks(const IniFile: TFileName);
var
  f: TStrings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  f := TStringList.Create;
  try
    f.LoadFromFile(IniFile);
    for i := Pred(f.Count) downto 1 do
      if (f[i] <> '') and (f[i][1] = '[') then
        f.Insert(i, '');
    f.SaveToFile(IniFile);
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that if there is already an empty line before the section name, this code will add another one. The loop goes down to one instead of zero assuming we don't need to add an empty line above the *first* section in the file.

Comment: @Andreas OT: I actually loathe `pred` in this context. I just cannot see the virtue in comparison to `Count-1`.

Comment: @David: I didn't say I like it. But since I haven't seen it used this way before, I got a bit excited. When using dynamic arrays, however, I do write `high(arr)` instead of `length(arr) - 1`. But that is a different thing, and I am sure you have nothing against that.

Comment: @Andreas AFAIK, on modern Delphi, `high(array)` will be inlined and will produce the same code as `length(array)-1`, for a dynamic array. For a `const array` as parameter, `high(array)` is to be prefered, because `high(array)` is the value stored on the stack.

Comment: @David `Count-1` and `pred(Count)` will produce the exact same asm code.

Comment: @A.Bouchez My preference is all about the human reader rather than the code that the compiler emits.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way would be to open the .ini file using [TMemIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TMemIniFile) instead of TIniFile.  It works the same way, but when it saves (UpdateFile), spaces are automatically added between sections.

Comment: Not only does it give you your spaces, it is also much more robust that the version reliant on private profile API!

Comment: BUT it also deletes all comments starting with ";" (which used to be the standard) from the file which is a pain in the lower back. It's the reason why I switched to "//" comments.

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding in the lines is indeed a workable solution. Another option is to create your own custom class inheriting from TIniFile and alter the behavior to include an extra line break before the section header.

Update: Use TCustomIniFile as the base class if you want to use this approach, not TIniFile.

Comment: @Bork, I've looked at the code, In Delphi 2007 that's not going to work. All does is calls to a DLL. Nothing to alter here unless you want to rewrite the code completely :-(

Comment: @Johan: Use `TMemIniFile` instead. This is easily tweaked.

Comment: @user TIniFile does not rely on the kernel, it's user space code.

Comment: @Craig and @Johan - Delphi documentation says you should inherit from TCustomIniFile if you want to make a custom class. I would check out that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple carriage return: Add(#13#10);